# Pickit3 programming problem

Tags: pic

For some time I have used the K150 PIC programmer but I was tired of some strange behaviour so I purchased an Original PICKIT3 programmer/debugger.
During programming a 16F648A I receive the following message. "You're attempting to program a release platform  with a debug build. Do you want to rebuild? This message keeps appearing time after time. 
I do not understand the reason nor can I find a solution to this problem.

After indicating that I do not want to rebuild the programming continues without problems. Reprogramming results in the same message.

When moving over to the debugger the program reports: Target Device (00001100) does not match expected Device ID (00001120). For this I also can not find an explanation. The same message happens with different projects that are all running without a problem.

So two questions. 
1. Why do I keep a sustained warning message during programming?
2. Why can there be a device mismatch?

I looked all over but can not find the reason.

Extra information: 
The program is generated in debug mode since that is what i require for the on line debug procedure.

Comment: Well are you sure that: a/ the chip you're trying to program is indeed 16F648A; b/ the project is set up to compile for that chip

Comment: Is there an option to compile and build in "release mode"?  I believe this could make a major difference.

Answer (score 3):

First, check that you aren't really trying to program a release platform with a debug build.  You haven't said anything about whether you are in fact building in debug mode or release mode.

The second problem is because you have MPLAB set up for a 18F2510 target instead of the 16F648A that is actually connected to the programmer.

There is also the possibility of a bad connection between the programmer and the chip.  Check the cable and the connectors.  If all that looks fine, then maybe you are having a crosstalk problem.  Try adding resistors and capacitors close to the PIC as I describe in my [In-circuit Serial Programming](http://www.embedinc.com/picprg/icsp.htm) writeup.

Comment: I am building in debug mode. Not clear where your 18F2510 target is comming from. In the MPLAB settings I have 16F648A. Tomorrow I start reading the writeup and learn from it.

Comment: @Deca: The ID code 1100h indicates a 18F2510.  If you're really sure you are building for a 16F648A, then there is apparently a connection problem between the programmer and the PIC.